# Problem with single Flutter Stream and 2 Stream builders

Tags: flutter

So I have Flutter ***Connectivity Stream.***

```
var subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged;
```

And 2 Pages (Tabs) in which I have one ***StreamBuilder***. For some reason, I can't use the same stream with 2 builders (for the first time it works but after I switch tab other ***StreamBuilder*** doesn't receive any data)

I tried making 2 separate Connectivity Streams it didn't work.

```
StreamBuilder(
      stream: subscription,
      builder: (BuildContext cntx,
          AsyncSnapshot<ConnectivityResult> snapShot) {
        if (!snapShot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
        var result = snapShot.data;
        switch (result) {
          case ConnectivityResult.none:
            CASE WITHOUT NETWORK
          case ConnectivityResult.wifi
             CASE WITH NETWROK
          default:

        }
      }
  )
```

I have 2 tabs like that for a different purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you'd like when you subscribe to the stream to get the last value it emitted. A `Stream` does not emit its current value if you subscribe to it again. If that is indeed what you want to do, you need to use [BehaviorSubject](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/BehaviorSubject-class.html).